# SharePoint 2013 Dispose checker

Tags: 2013, dispose, spdisposechecker

I've used SPDisposeCheck for SP2007/2010 and find it very useful for finding undisposed sp objects, but from this blog [post](http://gavinb.net/2013/08/08/spdisposecheck-do-not-use-for-sharepoint-2013/), it's mentioned that it's no longer working for 2013.

Is there any alternatives available?

Comment: SPCop will do the trick! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/torstenmandelkow/archive/2013/10/08/free-sharepoint-code-analysis-tool-available.aspx

Comment: SPCop served my purpose, consider writing an answer, i'll mark it

Comment: Added the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SPCop, the free tool of the SPCAF framework, will do the trick and even more. Have a look here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/torstenmandelkow/archive/2013/10/08/free-sharepoint-code-analysis-tool-available.aspx

Comment: For what it's worth, SPCop and the SPCAF community edition no longer exist. SPCAF is a commercial-only product. You need a license to even see the report of which vulnerabilities/problems were detected in your code. I was rather disappointed to find this out, so I figured I would let anyone else know who happens upon this StackExchange post and believes they've found their answer.

Comment: This page is no longer available. please can you post any other url

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SPDisposechecker. In this tool, what you have to do is give the path of dll and the file where you want the output file.
Example,

Perform SPDisposeChecker on dlls using command line

C:\Program Files\Microsoft\SharePoint Dispose Check>SPDisposeCheck C:\CODE\DisposeCheckDllfolder >Log100DII.xml

where 1) C:\Program Files\Microsoft\SharePoint Dispose Check     -->   path of dispose checker exe

2) SPDisposeCheck --> command(Keyword)

3) C:\CODE\DisposeCheckDllfolder --> where the dll of your solution is kept.

4) Log100DII.xml --> output file name will generate in the same folder of dll

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2a3811c6-72d7-4948-ae34-dd7cf5bca099/sharepoint-dispose-checker-tool-and-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: But from the blog, it's mentioned that the tool doesn't work for 2013, it will give false negative